# Calculate the value of PI using `pi = x * sin(180 / x)`

Tags: ruby, math, pi

I have a problem using `sin`. I did:

```
include Math

puts sin(5) # => -0.9589242746631385
```

But when I type `sin(5)` into my calculator, it outputs `0.087155742`. Likewise, I tried to calculate the value of PI using the equation pi = x * sin(180 / x) and got a problem although I got the value of PI with it on my calculator.

```
include Math

puts "Enter the value of x"
x = gets.to_f
num = 180 / x

pie = x * sin(num)
puts pie
```

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. How can a constant PI depend on a variable x? And what does x represent in the first place?

Comment: Change `sin(num)` to `Math.sum(num)`. See [Math::sim](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Math.html#method-c-sin). I have not checked for other mistakes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, how `sum` is related to this question at all? The question is obviously about the sine trigonometric function

Comment: @sawa x is imputed by the user. I got the equation from https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi  Method #4

Comment: @SergGr, I thought I had corrected that before posting. I meant to just make the point that `sin` is a module method of `Math`.

Comment: @sawa it’s a mathematical identity that sin(x)/x goes to 1 as x goes to infinity, where sin() is the usual radians function. This is the somewhat different case where sin expects degrees, hence is pi/180 different.

Comment: @Bob, I am hesitant to question a professor at my alma mater (go, Bears!), but don't you mean `x*sin(1/x)` approaches `1` as `x ->  ∞`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch, thanks. I actually intended as x-> 0, which is the OPs case.

Comment: Blair, you don't need to `include Math`, at least in MRI. (It's part of the Ruby core.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Okay sweet thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is for a calculation of the sin of an angle in degrees.

Most, maybe all, computer language sin() functions expect the angle to be in radians.

Unfortunately, you need to have a value for pi to convert from one to another, so unless you can find a sin-in-degrees implementation you’re somewhat stuck.

This is because your formula comes from the 2×π/360 or π/180 conversion between radians and degrees.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining. I never knew the angle had to be in radians.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also multiply by cos(180/x).  Let x grow large and you get out.

I just did this proof.

Actually I did another proof lol.

Based on using area I got the cos term, but based on circumference, just the xsin(180/x).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).